# Shell script to select all numbers from a file

Tags: shell

I have a file that contains words and numbers at random positions. I must write a shell script that adds all the numbers from the file.

I thought about something like this:

```
filename=$1
words=` echo $filename `
sum=0
for word in words;
do
    #if $word is number, add to sum
done
```

How can I verify if something is a number in shell? Or this whole approach is wrong?

Comment: Can you show some sample file to "play" with it? Also, are all integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for exapmle use this:

```
grep -ow '[0-9]*' file | awk '{count+=$1} END{print count}'
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -ow '[0-9]*' file` gets all the blocks of numbers of the file. `-w` matches just words, so that `a23b` won't be a match.
- `awk '{count+=$1} END{print count}'` loops through the `grep` result adding each one of the numbers to the `count` variable. Finally, prints the result.

#### Example

```
$ cat a
aa b23 23 55
adf 23 23 62l

$ grep -ow '[0-9]*' a | awk '{count+=$1} END{print count}'
124

$ grep -ow '[0-9]*' a
23
55
23
23
```

Comment: This works for most cases, but it should not select words like "a2a", "2a2" and co.

Comment: That's why I asked you to provide some sample data.

Comment: I think $ grep -o -w '[0-9]*' a | awk '{count+=$1} END{print count}' should work

Comment: @user3002428 oh, you made it! I did try several ways but this is definitely the best. Updating with this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash version:

```
while read line; do
    set $line
    while (( $# > 0 )); do
        [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && n="$1" && (( total += n ))
        shift
    done
done
echo $total
```